# Don't want to upload extra files from AWS Elastic Search to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I am following below link for "Use Amazon S3 to Store a Single Amazon Elasticsearch Service Index" https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-amazon-s3-to-store-a-single-amazon-elasticsearch-service-index/

I am successfully able to upload the indices from AWS Elasticseach to S3 bucket. But I noticed that extra files are also uploaded along with indices. I don't want to upload extra files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g7Ls.png)

What is the meaning of incompatible-snapshot file? When I downloaded this file, I found below content in this file.

**{"incompatible-snapshots":[]}**